# Reliable way to transport data over 1-2 km distance

Tags: rf, communication, wireless

I am looking for some way to transport data (around 3000Kbps) omnidirectional. Transmitter should not weight more than 300 grams but receiver can be much heavier. The range I am trying to achieve is 1-2km line of sight. Is there any reliable hardware to fulfill this role?

Comment: Check out what your country requires in terms of radio legislation. You say "omni" but then you talk about a transmitter and receiver as if it were a unidirectional link - can you be clear about this. Also do you mean 3kbps or 3Mbps? You might also need to think about how much data in one day you need to transport because a very reliable method is storing a day's worth then transporting it by road to its destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFi will do this quite easily. It's the only consumer wireless data system that gets you a few Mbps.

With a directional antenna on one end and a regular wifi device on the other, you should get a link at at about 2 km. I have tried this, with a 22 dBi antenna on one side of a valley, and my laptop on the other side, about 2 km apart.

Set the WiFi devices to use the lowest speed, 5 Mbps mode, so they don't continuously try to move up to higher speeds, then fail and move down again.

If one end is flying, you will need to aim the base station antenna... this could be automated with a GPS at both ends.

Comment: Good point about the gps tracking... I use 2.4Ghz to control the device that will carry the transmitter, could I possibly use 5.8GHz wifi device to avoid interference? And also do you recommend some specific device that is powerful enough?

Comment: Yes using 5.8 GHz will probably reduce the interference. Just be sure to pick a channel that's not exactly double the 2.4 GHz frequency you're using.  I don't know any particular device. At 5 GHz you might need about 26 dBi, at least a a 40 cm dish or panel.